# Setting a Texture in a shader's constant buffer in D3D10

Tags: c++, directx, textures, shader, direct3d10

Ok I have a shader compiled up under D3D10.

I am obtaining a shader reflection to get details of all the constants/globals in the shader.  However I'm a little confused on something ... how do I set a texture to a constant buffer?

I assume I don't just Map the constant buffer and copy the ID3D10Texture pointer into it ... I assume I use an ID3D10ShaderResourceView but I'm just unsure of how I set it in the constant buffer.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't bind a texture to a constant buffer. You bind textures, via views, to a stage (here GS stage) using method:

```
void GSSetShaderResources(
  [in]  UINT StartSlot,
  [in]  UINT NumViews,
  [in]  ID3D10ShaderResourceView *ppShaderResourceViews
);
```

Views and CBs are actually two separate things.

Comment: Ok I'm beginning to realise this but how do I tie a given shader global "Texture2D" to a given slot?

Comment: Maybe I should start a new question...?  Damn me for using an XP macine to attempt to do DX10 stuff earlier ;)

Comment: You have to use a register attribute to tie an SRV (on a buffer or texture) to a given slot: e.g:
Texture2D<float4> diffuse : register(t0) //slot 0 here

Comment: Then this SRV is bound to ppShaderResourceViews[0+StartSlot] when calling *SetShaderResources.